# segfault when calling pthread_create() c++ linux

Tags: c++, linux, segmentation-fault, pthreads, posix

Haven't been here for a while but I'm stuck...
I can't seem to figure out where the problem lies with this code

logger.cpp

```
#include "logger.h"
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void* __logger(void* data)  // dummy function
{
    sleep(10);
    return NULL;
}

logger_t::logger_t()
{
    // create a pipe for communicating with thread
    if (pipe(fd) == -1) // something went wrong
    {
        // error here
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    // now create the thread that will write to the log
    if (pthread_create(log_pid, NULL, &__logger, NULL))  // something went wrong
    {
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}

logger_t::~logger_t()
{
    close(fd[1]);     // close read end of pipe, logging thread will read EOF and exit
    if (pthread_join(*log_pid, NULL))
    {
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}
```

logger.h

```
#ifndef LOGGER_H
#define LOGGER_H
#include <pthread.h>

class logger_t
{
    public:
        logger_t();
        ~logger_t();

    private:
        int fd[2];
        pthread_t* log_pid;
};
#endif // LOGGER_H
```

main.cpp

```
#include "logger.h"

int main()
{
    logger_t proglog;
    return 0;
}
```

The code compiles just fine but when I run it I get a segmentation fault during the pthread_create() call... Any ideas? I have stripped away everything in the program and I still get the same crash...

Comment: C++ has a thread api. Don't use pthreads.

Answer (score 2):

From the man page of `pthread_create()`:

> Before returning, a successful call to pthread_create() stores the ID
>          of the new thread in the buffer pointed to by thread;

The `thread` argument should point to something valid - in your case you are passing in an un-initialized pointer. Perhaps this has something to do with it. To confirm, run it in a debugger (such as gdb) and take a look.

Also, as you indicate this is c++, you should really use `std::thread()`.

Comment: So you should use a `pthread_t log_pid;` and not a `pthread_t* log_pid;`. Then use the address of it: `pthread_create(&log_pid, NULL, &__logger, NULL)` and in the join use the variable itself: `pthread_join(*log_pid, NULL)`.

Comment: @Andre _"use the variable itself"_ so remove the `*`

Comment: Great thanks! Yup, changing to a variable instead of a pointer did the trick. I'll look into std::thread() as well